# Problem with custom vertical UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, uislider

I'm trying to implement vertical slider with no thumb, that reacts to touches on it's track. I have subclassed UISlider and everything goes fine in horizontal slider, but when I'm transforming slider to vertical there is wierd stuff with coordinates going on. May be there is other way to implement this? Please, give me right direction, thanks!

I'm using this code for slider now:

```
@implementation MMTouchSlider

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    self.value = self.minimumValue + (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue) * (touchLocation.x / self.frame.size.width);

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value {

    CGRect thumbRect = [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];
    return thumbRect;
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Can you provide a screenshot too?

Comment: It's not easy to provide the screenshot, because it's a glitch with touch. Slider value is not where I clicked on track, something like that.

Comment: Can you provide the expected touch coordinates and the actual touch coordinates reported?  Perhaps they may contain a clue to what is hapening.

Comment: I just changed width to height and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to make a vertical slider - just use 270 degree rotation!

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 10)];
float angleInDegrees = 270;
float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (M_PI/180);
slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
[self.view addSubView:slider];
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I'm using this code in viewDidLoad to make it vertical. May be I should be more clear about wierd stuff going on. When slider is vertical, I click on track and slider's value is not where I clicked. When it's horisontal, everything works great.